# Cannot figure out what's wrong with my schema

Tags: database

It keep saying

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Here is my Schema:

```
function artx_partner_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['artx_partner'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for artx_partner.',
    'fields' => array(
      'partner_id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a partnership.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'User identifier.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'Node identifier.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'product_id' => array(
        'description' => 'Identifier for a product.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'reqtime' => array(
        'description' => 'time stamp of the request',
        'type' => 'datetime:normal',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'restime' => array(
        'description' => 'time stamp of the response to request',
        'type' => 'datetime:normal',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'status' => array(
        'description' => 'the status of the request, pending(0)/AC(1)/Rej(2)',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('partner_id'),
    'unique keys' => array('unique' => array('uid', 'nid', 'product_id')),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'owner' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
      ),
      'product_display' => array(
        'table' => 'node',
        'columns' => array('nid' => 'nid'),
      ),
      'product' => array(
        'table' => 'commerce_product',
        'columns' => array('product_id' => 'product_id'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned attribute is not supported with datetime. Following code will create table for you.

```
function artx_partner_schema() {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['artx_partner'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for artx_partner.',
    'fields' => array(
      'partner_id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a partnership.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'User identifier.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'Node identifier.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'product_id' => array(
        'description' => 'Identifier for a product.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'reqtime' => array(
        'description' => 'time stamp of the request',
        'type' => 'datetime:normal',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'restime' => array(
        'description' => 'time stamp of the response to request',
        'type' => 'datetime:normal',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'status' => array(
        'description' => 'the status of the request, pending(0)/AC(1)/Rej(2)',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('partner_id'),
    'unique keys' => array('unique' => array('uid', 'nid', 'product_id')),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'owner' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
      ),
      'product_display' => array(
        'table' => 'node',
        'columns' => array('nid' => 'nid'),
      ),
      'product' => array(
        'table' => 'commerce_product',
        'columns' => array('product_id' => 'product_id'),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what others have said, your use of `'mysql_type' => 'datetime'` is OK (and will work as you intend, provided the database is MySQL).

What triggers the PDOException is the use of the `unsigned` attribute.  This was first pointed out in the answer *Pushpinder Rana* - +1 from me for that. However, I would not use his suggested schema verbatim: The line `'type' => 'datetime:normal'` is not portable and *will* trigger a PDOexception if the code is ported to a site that uses a database engine that does not support `datetime`.  (The fact that `datetime` is not supported by all is the reason for the change in Drupal 7.)

Use of the fallback type `datetime:normal` for the case when the DB is not MySQL will not work as you intend for *all* database engines.  For portable code, you should use a fallback. I recommend that in this case, you provide a fallback type `varchar` for the case that the database is *not* MySQL.

(While [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) suggests one uses `text` as a generic fallback, I prefer `varchar` for `datetime`.  Both are variable length generic fields.  On PostgreSQL they're equivalent, but on some other database engines, `varchar` is slightly faster for short strings such as datetime.)

I.e.: replace the relevant part of your schema with the following:

```
  'reqtime' => array(
    'description' => 'time stamp of the request',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
  'restime' => array(
    'description' => 'time stamp of the response to request',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
```

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7 suggests `text` as the fallback. Or just omitting `'type'` if it's always going to be used on MySQL anyway.

However, given that the database *is* MySQL, why is the fallback causing an error?

Comment: This answer is omitting the `'unsigned' => TRUE,` (which Pushpinder Rana first pointed out is not supported) without actually pointing out that this has changed. So whilst the revised schema will probably work, it will not be for the reason stated in this answer.

Comment: Entire section: `'mysql_type', 'pgsql_type', 'sqlite_type', etc.: If you need to use a record type not included in the officially supported list of types above, you can specify a type for each database backend. In this case, you can leave out the type parameter, but be advised that your schema will fail to load on backends that do not have a type specified. A possible solution can be to use the "text" type as a fallback.`

Comment: I agree that a fallback is better for portable code, but if you're using a type that isn't supported in all engines then the portability of the code is already compromised. Reading the spec again I realise that `text` is a generic fallback suggestion, and your suggestion of `varchar` is probably better for a datetime fallback, depending on the database engine.

Comment: @PaulGregory, I agree with you regarding `'unsigned' => TRUE`. Kudos to @PushpinderRana for spotting that. I've updated my answer. I've also added a note about `varchar` vs `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Below field in your schema definition is causing problem...

```
  'reqtime' => array(
    'description' => 'time stamp of the request',
    'type' => 'datetime:normal',
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
  'restime' => array(
    'description' => 'time stamp of the response to request',
    'type' => 'datetime:normal',
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
```

Try removing type attribute.. It should support mysql_type attribute..

Drupal doesn't support field of type datetime. It's removed from Drupal 7.

Find more information below..

https://drupal.org/node/159605

Comment: Drupal 7 doesn't support `type` of datetime, but does support `mysql_type` of datetime.